# Javascript not firing properly on Mobile - iOS / Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, ios

I have a full screen overlay menu that appears on mobile.

[image: Mobile Menu]

All of the sections on this menu appear in the DOM on that page, I want to be able to click the link and it scroll down to the relevant ID element. This is currently working on desktop devices, but on iOS / Android the script isn't firing.

```
  $('.on-page-item').click(function(event) {
       var $this = $(this);
       var href = $this.attr('href');
       var changedhref = href.substring(1);
       var target = changedhref;
        $( "button.overlay-close" ).trigger( "click" );
        $( "div.demo" ).scrollTop(changedhref);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 500);
       classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
  });
```

Would you know the reason that this isn't firing?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bind any event with `.on()` method, then you can bind for both devices like:

```
$('.on-page-item').on('click touchstart', function(event) {
```

`click`: for desktop devices
`touchstart`: for mobile devices

Comment: It also works with jQuery's `.click` and for mobile applications I would recommend using it anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind for both desktop and mobile like this:

```
$('.on-page-item').on('click touchstart', function(event){
  //your code here
});
```

Also MDN has a great reference for your future touch events that I bookmarked:

[Touch Events - Web API Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)